# What does docker container exit status 255 mean?

Tags: docker

The [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering) mentions

> You can use a filter to locate containers that exited with status of
>   137 meaning a SIGKILL(9) killed them

I'm wondering does exit status 255 mean anything special?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you see that on a docker ps, showing a container with a status "`Exited (255)`", that means its main entrpypoint/command process stopped with that status.

And 255 simply means "there was an error", but does not tell you much beside that.

---

Hence the article "[5 ways to debug an exploding Docker container](https://medium.com/@pimterry/5-ways-to-debug-an-exploding-docker-container-4f729e2c0aa8)" from [Tim Perry](https://twitter.com/pimterry), to investigate further:

```sh
docker logs <container_id>

docker stats <container_id>

docker cp <container_id>:/path/to/useful/file /local-path

docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash

docker commit <container_id> my-broken-container && \
docker run -it my-broken-container /bin/bash
```

Comment: How to dig deeper in order to know more about the error ?

Comment: @MohamedKamelBouzekria https://medium.com/@pimterry/5-ways-to-debug-an-exploding-docker-container-4f729e2c0aa8 for instance.