# Howto connect with PHP to a MS SQL Server within a Docker setup?

Tags: php, sql-server, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to connect to a MS SQL server with PHP in a Docker environment.

I followed [this instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52821353/415353) for my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3.10-apache

RUN apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev
RUN pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
```

The following two lines are added to the `php.ini`:

```
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
extension=sqlsrv.so
```

The `phpinfo()` shows this:

[image: phpfinfo for PDO]

Now I am trying to connect to the MS SQL Server (which is not part of the docker environment):

```
$server   = 'MyServer';
$database = 'MyDB';
$username = 'MyUser';
$password = 'MyPassword';

# Connect
try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server;Database=$database", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Error connecting to SQL Server: ".$e->getMessage());
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Error connecting to SQL Server: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension
>   requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with
>   SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for
>   SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712

Can someone point me in the right direction? What exactly do I need to do?

Comment: There's a link to this page on the page the error links to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 There are instructions there for installing the driver on linux. I haven't done this before, but I assume you should be able to just add that installation to your dockerfile.

Comment: Microsoft also has this: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/tree/master/oss-drivers/msphpsql It's an older PHP version than you're using, but looks to be a good starting point at least.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I have triend the github link before, but when calling the line `RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -` I got this error: `Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -' returned a non-zero code: 255`.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think the 255 error gives you much info about the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691770/what-does-docker-container-exit-status-255-mean There's a link in a comment on the answer there that may help with troubleshooting that.